# Creating a Horizontal Selection Menu with Arrow Key Navigation in Python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, inquirer

I'm working on a Python command-line application, and I need to implement a horizontal selection menu with arrow key navigation. I want the user to be able to navigate through a list of options displayed horizontally and select an option using left, right, top and bottom arrow keys. I've tried using the inquirer library, but it doesn't seem to support this feature out of the box.

I have a custom Python [procedure](https://gist.github.com/dev-ghoudi/dc5318ede727ca0c7f87e6074afbc4f3), that can display a list of options horizontally, but I'm not sure how to integrate arrow key navigation with it.

Is there a Python library or a way to modify my display_horizontally procedure so that it supports arrow key navigation? Alternatively, are there other libraries or code examples that I can use to achieve this functionality?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions, including how to integrate my existing procedure with a solution that provides arrow key navigation. Thank you!